# Why does eclipse CDT extract function feature want to reformat unrelated code in my .cc file?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have some C++ code that contains 5 or so lines of code that I want to refactor into a function. When I right-click->refactor->extract function, the refactor generates the function correctly, but it insists also on reformatting a large chunk of code that has nothing to do with the code I'm refactoring. Furthermore, neither the reformatted code nor the generated function fits my current style (K&R modified by me) as near as I can tell.

Why does it do this?

Is there a way to get it to follow my code style?

Is there a way to turn it off?